# Posicionar componentes dentro de um JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout

Estou tentando posicionar alguns componentes em uma tela, porém não esta dando muito certo. Então criei um exemplo meio simples, para ilustrar o problema. Aceito sujeitações para aperfeiçoar a maneira com a qual estou fazendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Observação:** Sempre que adiciono um painel dentro de uma aba, eu não consigo fazer ele ficar próximo a borda da aba, ele sempre fica longe.

```
package layout;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TesteLayout extends JFrame {

    public JPanel jpCampos = new JPanel();
    private final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private final MeuJTextField a = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField b = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField c = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField d = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField e = new MeuJTextField("");

    private final MeuJTextField aa = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField bb = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField cc = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField dd = new MeuJTextField("");
    private final MeuJTextField ee = new MeuJTextField("");

    class MeuJTextField extends JTextField {

        public MeuJTextField(String nome) {
            //setColumns(120);
            setText("teste de layouts");
        }
    }

    public TesteLayout() {
        add(adicionaPaines());
        //setSize(600, 300);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    private JComponent adicionaPaines() {
        JPanel adicionaPaines = new JPanel();
        adicionaPaines.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel painel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Painel superior");
        painel.add(label);

        JPanel painel2 = new JPanel();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Aqui vai um label");
        painel2.add(label2);
        label2.setForeground(new Color(99, 49, 131));

        adicionaComponente(1, 1, 1, 1, painel, adicionaPaines);
        adicionaComponente(2, 1, 1, 1, painel2, adicionaPaines);
        adicionaComponente(3, 1, 1, 1, adionaAba(), adicionaPaines);
        return adicionaPaines;
    }

    private JComponent adionaAba() {
        JPanel painelAbas = new JPanel();
        painelAbas.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        tabbedPane.addTab("Teste", tela());
        tabbedPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 250));
        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.BEFORE_LINE_BEGINS);
        return painelAbas;
    }

    private JComponent tela() {
        JPanel tela = new JPanel();

        JPanel painel1 = new JPanel();
        painel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        painel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Painel 01"));
        adicionaComponente(1, 1, 1, 1, painel1, tela);
        adicionaComponente(2, 1, 1, 1, a, painel1);
        adicionaComponente(3, 1, 1, 1, b, painel1);
        adicionaComponente(4, 1, 1, 1, c, painel1);
        adicionaComponente(4, 3, 1, 1, d, painel1);
        adicionaComponente(5, 1, 1, 1, e, painel1);

        JPanel painel2 = new JPanel();
        painel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        painel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Painel 02"));
        adicionaComponente(1, 1, 1, 1, painel2, tela);
        adicionaComponente(2, 1, 1, 1, aa, painel2);
        adicionaComponente(3, 1, 1, 1, bb, painel2);
        adicionaComponente(4, 1, 1, 1, cc, painel2);
        adicionaComponente(4, 3, 1, 1, dd, painel2);
        adicionaComponente(5, 1, 1, 1, ee, painel2);

        return tela;
    }

    public void adicionaComponente(int linha, int coluna, int linhas, int colunas, JComponent componente, JPanel painel) {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridy = linha;
        gbc.gridx = coluna;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5); // ↑, ←, ↓, →

        if (painel == null) {
            painel = jpCampos;
        }
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridheight = linhas;
        gbc.gridwidth = colunas;
        painel.add(componente, gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()
                -> {
            TesteLayout layout = new TesteLayout();
            layout.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual o problema. É posicionar internamente ou os paineis externos? Porque o código não fica como na imagem.

Comment: @diegofm esse é problema, estou tentado fazer como na imagem, mais não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Precisa ser com gridbaglayout? Você escolheu justo o mais complexo de todos.

Comment: @diegofm se possível, esse método de adicionar componentes me salva muito quando estendo pra outras telas

Comment: Mas é obrigatório? Esse layout eu não manjo muito, acredito ser possivel fazer isso mesclando os outros e ficar algo mais simples e facil de dar manutenção(gridbaglayout é complicado pra manutencao de layout).

Comment: @diegofm pode fazer com outro sim ! qualquer coisa eu tento fazer algo parecido com o adiciona componentes, so que ai usando outros gerenciadores.

Comment: Você usa esse método para criar outras telas? Isso é uma má pratica, cada tela deve ser a unica responsável por si, usar um metodo externo pra construir outra tela pode te gerar problemas.

Comment: Eu tenho uma classe, para adicionar botoes e repetir outros métodos comuns entre as telas, esse método so fica nela, ai cada tela que herda eu so defino a posição. Mais para simplificar eu fiz desse jeito ai no exemplo. Assim fica bem orientado a objetos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível fazer isso utilizando apenas [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html):

Passando [`BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html#Y_AXIS) no construtor desta classe, você indica ao layout que alinhe os componentes adicionados conforme o eixo Y, ou seja, adiciona-os verticalmente. Este layout precisa ser aplicado ao container principal do `JFrame`, e depois adicionado outros 3 subcontainers. Os demais componentes você pode distribuir, como eu fiz no exemplo, dentro dos 3 subcontainers principais.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class MultiPanel extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel painelSuperior;
    private JPanel painelLabel;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JPanel painelTab;
    private JPanel painel1;
    private JPanel panel2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->  {
            new MultiPanel().setVisible(true);
        });
    }


    public MultiPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //este painel será o container principal da tela
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        painelSuperior = new JPanel();
        painelSuperior.setBorder(new TitledBorder( "Painel Superior"));
        contentPane.add(painelSuperior);

        painelLabel = new JPanel();
        painelLabel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Painel do Label"));
        contentPane.add(painelLabel);

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        painelLabel.add(lblNewLabel);

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

        painelTab = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("New tab", painelTab);
        //para que os paineis 1 e 2 fiquem alinhados horizontalmente
        painelTab.setLayout(new BoxLayout(painelTab, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        //paineis adicionados a aba do tabbedpane
        painel1 = new JPanel();
        painel1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("painel 1"));
        painelTab.add(painel1);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("painel 2"));
        painelTab.add(panel2);
        pack();
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais detalhes sobre layouts Managers e o `BoxLayout` pode ser encontra na documentação:

[A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

[How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Comment: como vc alinhou assim ? X_AXIS coloca sozinho, não identifiquei você ordenando por algum tipo de coordenada. Nossa parece muito mais prático

Comment: @RoyalJava nessa linha: `contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Comment: para adicionar os textFields, eu continuo a usar o adicionaComponentes ?

Comment: @RoyalJava como eu disse nos comentários, a solução é totalmente alternativa ao seu código. não creio que aquele metodo funcione aqui. Há 3 paineis principais e é dentro desses 3 que você pode distribuir demais componentes(ou outros paineis mais internos).

Comment: @RoyalJava A resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no`v` a esquerda da resposta :)